# When scroll page down appear and dissapear element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Whenever I scroll page down to bottom of B element my sticky element (which is the display none; on the top) must be appear and if I scroll page up to top of my B element my sticky must be hidden.

my codes

[image]

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>

        <ul class="sticky">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="a"></div>
            <div class="b"></div>
            <div class="c"></div>
        </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width:1020px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.container>div{
        width:100%;
        height:300px;
        background:#f0f0f0;
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        margin:100px 0;
    }
.a:after{
    content:"A";
    font-size:250px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:300px;
    display:block;
    color:#999;
}
.b:after{
    content:"B";
    font-size:250px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:300px;
    display:block;
    color:#999;
}
.c:after{
    content:"C";
    font-size:250px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:300px;
    display:block;
    color:#999;
}
ul.sticky{
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    background:#f0f0f0;
    height:50px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #ccc;
    display:none;
}
ul.sticky:after,ul.sticky:before{
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}
ul.sticky li a{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    line-height:50px;
    padding:0 30px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#999;
}
ul.sticky li a:hover{
    background:#999;
    color:#f0f0f0;
}
```

(in my css I have sticky element which is none appear)

JQUERY

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        /* I dont't know what I have to do */
    });
});
```

[click to see on codepen](http://codepen.io/yedincifirat/pen/BLaOVW)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved it by doing this, it appears after you pass the bottom of .b and hides if not:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > $(".b").offset().top+$(".b").height()){
            $(".sticky").show();
        }else{
            $(".sticky").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: by the way I need another example I have input element on my page if it empty show my sticky when I scroll down.

http://codepen.io/yedincifirat/pen/ALBJXG

Comment: You need to show your sticky element if an specific input field in your page is empty? if we are talking about an input text field you can do something like `if($(".input").val() == ""){ $(".sticky").show(); }else{ $(".sticky").hide(); }` in the scroll event, I recommend you to create another specific question for this tho.

Answer (score 2):

### Suggested Solution:

Add this to your jquery code:

```
$(function() {
    var targetOffset = $(".b").offset().top; //based on this div, the sticky element should appear
    var $w = $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ( $w.scrollTop() > targetOffset ) {
            $(".sticky").show(); //show the sticky element
        } else {
          $(".sticky").hide();//hide the sticky element
        }
    });
});
```

> Whenever I scroll page down to bottom of B element my sticky element must appear

[image]

> If I scroll page up to top of my B element my sticky must be hidden

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the scrollTop of the document to see how far you are from the top, then compare that to the scrollTop of the element you are scrolling to (to see if you have reached it)

The reason you should cache your selectors, like I have, is that the onScroll event triggers A LOT. So if you have $('ul.sticky').dosomethign inside of $.scroll(), you are A.) creating that jquery object, B.) querying the DOM C.) doing stuff. This can get rather expensive for performance. Typically if you are going to do an onScroll event handler, you should add a debounce or throttle to it to limit the number of times the handler function is called.

```js
$(function() {

  var $sticky = $('ul.sticky');
  var bToTop = $('.b').scrollTop();
 
    $(window).scroll(function() {

   if($(document).scrollTop() > bToTop){
    $sticky.show();
   }
   else  {
    $sticky.hide();
   }
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
 width:1020px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.container>div{
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  background:#f0f0f0;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  margin:100px 0;
 }
.a:after{
 content:"A";
 font-size:250px;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:300px;
 display:block;
 color:#999;
}
.b:after{
 content:"B";
 font-size:250px;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:300px;
 display:block;
 color:#999;
}
.c:after{
 content:"C";
 font-size:250px;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:300px;
 display:block;
 color:#999;
}
ul.sticky{
 list-style-type:none;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 background:#f0f0f0;
 height:50px;
 border-bottom:5px solid #ccc;
 display:none;
}
ul.sticky:after,ul.sticky:before{
 content:"";
 display:table;
 clear:both;
}
ul.sticky li a{
 display:block;
 float:left;
 line-height:50px;
 padding:0 30px;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#999;
}
ul.sticky li a:hover{
 background:#999;
 color:#f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <head>
  
 </head>
 <body>
  
  <ul class="sticky">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="container">
   <div class="a"></div>
   <div class="b"></div>
   <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
  
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
 <body>
</html>
```

If you want to show the sticky only when you have reached the end of element b, you can do `var bToTop = $('.b').height() + $('.b').scrollTop();`

Comment: hi but it works just only scrolling down.it must be if I reached end of B element

Comment: Did you try what I have at the end of my answer? If you mean when b scrolls off the screen, then you can do `var bToTop = ($('.b').height() * 2) + $('.b').scrollTop();`

Answer (score 1):

[codepen](http://codepen.io/rohitchopra/pen/ORJBzk)

```
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
   if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 600) {
     $("ul").css({"display":"initial"});
   } 
    if($(document).scrollTop() <=600) {
     $("ul").css({"display":"none"});
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be the proper and correct solution.

Just change the `display: none` to `visibility: hidden;`.

```js
$(function() {
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(".a").offset().top + $(".a").height()) {
   $(".sticky").css({
    "visibility": "visible"
   });
  } else {
   $(".sticky").css({
    "visibility": "hidden"
   });
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.container {
 width:1020px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.container>div{
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  background:#f0f0f0;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  margin:100px 0;
 }
.a:after{
 content:"A";
 font-size:250px;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:300px;
 display:block;
 color:#999;
}
.b:after{
 content:"B";
 font-size:250px;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:300px;
 display:block;
 color:#999;
}
.c:after{
 content:"C";
 font-size:250px;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:300px;
 display:block;
 color:#999;
}
ul.sticky{
 list-style-type:none;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 background:#f0f0f0;
 height:50px;
 border-bottom:5px solid #ccc;
 visibility: hidden;
}
ul.sticky:after,ul.sticky:before{
 content:"";
 display:table;
 clear:both;
}
ul.sticky li a{
 display:block;
 float:left;
 line-height:50px;
 padding:0 30px;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#999;
}
ul.sticky li a:hover{
 background:#999;
 color:#f0f0f0;
}
.show{
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  
 </head>
 <body>
  
  <ul class="sticky">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="container">
   <div class="a"></div>
   <div class="b"></div>
   <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
  
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
 <body>
</html>
```